# How to get the Speed Dial and Trash bookmark folders

Tags: opera-extension

Is there any reliable way to get the Speed Dial and Trash bookmark folders?

Are the ids of the system bookmark folders the same for all installations?
I could do a loop though with an id match but I'm not sure if the ids are the same for all Opera users.

**EDIT**: Just tested, the ids are not the same. One Opera instance in English and the Speed Dial folder id is 7 another Opera instance with language set to Chinese and the Speed Dial Folder id is 8.

I could do a loop through with a name match but what if the user uses another language? The system bookmark folders' names are automatically translated rendering the name match failed.

No id match and no name match, anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `chrome.bookmarks.getRootByName(string rootName, function callback)`, where:

- rootName is "speed_dial", "trash", "unsorted", "bookmarks_bar", "other", "mobile", "user_root", "shared",
- callback is a function that will return BookmarkTreeNode via a parameter - just simply `function(BookmarkTreeNode results) {...};`

As an example (I've never tested it but I infer it should work OK):

```
chrome.bookmarks.getRootByName("speed_dial", function(result) {
    console.log("Name: " + result.title);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it the next time I dive into coding again.